# How to convert array inside list into list item using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have array as list item inside a list that I want to convert into list later on. Code below is a result from looping over **a** and **b**. 

**Output**

```
>>> 
[[2, 0], [0, 0]]
[array([5, 7]), array([5, 5])]
[[1, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0], [1], [1]]
[array([5, 6, 4]), array([6, 6, 6]), array([3]), array([3])]
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
[array([4, 5]), array([4, 5])]
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
>>> type(b)
<type 'list'>
```

I use tolist() function to convert them into list but there is one line that is not successful:
**Output**

```
>>> 
[[2, 0], [0, 0]]
[[5, 7], [5, 5]]
[[1, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0], [1], [1]]
[array([5, 6, 4]), array([6, 6, 6]), array([3]), array([3])]
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
[[4, 5], [4, 5]]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do? or the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from numpy import *

# Your original list of numpy arrays ...
b = [array([5, 7]), array([5, 5])]
# ... can be converted to list of lists
c = [list(x) for x in b]
```